# Passing Multiple Arguments Including A List To A Function

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

This is what I want to happen:

```
[m | m<-[1..1000], k<-[3,5], m `mod` k == 0]
```

When I put that code in the console I get the result I want but when I try to turn it into a generalized function Haskell is just spitting out tons of errors and I cannot figure out how to make it work.

This is what I have:

```
multiplesOfKLessThanN :: Num a => [a] -> a -> [a]
multiplesOfKLessThanN ks n = [m | m<-[1..n], k<-ks, m `mod` k == 0]

problem1 = putStrLn(show(multiplesOfKLessThanN([3,5] 1000)))
main = problem1
```

One Such Error I am getting:

> Couldn't match expected type 'Integer -> [a0]' with actual type '[Integer]'

I also get other errors but inconsistently. This is something I have noticed with Haskell, it likes to change error messages even when the code hasn't changed at all like wtf?

Comment: It definitely shouldn't be the case that an error message changes when the code hasn't changed at all. If you have instructions that we can follow to observe this behavior ourselves, please post them -- if not here, then on the GHC bug tracker.

Answer (score 8):

Your use of `mutliplesOfKLessThanN` is not correct

```hs
mutliplesOfKLessThanN([3,5] 1000)
```

Is not interpreted by Haskell as

> Apply `mutliplesOfKLessThanN` with `[3,5]` and `1000`.

but instead it is interpteted as

> Apply `[3,5]` to `1000` and apply `multiplesOfKLessThanN` to the result.

I think your misconception is in how function application occurs.  In many languages function application requires parentheses e.g. `f(x)`.  For Haskell parentheses only ever mean "do this operation first", and function application is achieved by putting things next to each other.  So `f(x)` works in Haskell because it is the same as `f x`, but `f(x y)` is the same as `f(x(y))` and tells Haskell to evaluate `x y` first and then give it to `f`.

With your code Haskell can't apply `[3,5]` as a function, which is what Haskell is telling you, it expected a function (in fact a specific type of function).

The proper way to write this would be

```hs
multiplesOfKLessThanN [3,5] 1000
```

This should handle that main error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

So the error here is a type error because you are trying to make a more general type a be used by the function modulo. If you look at the type mod it expects an integral type class changing your constraint from Num to Integral should resolve your issue